# HTML form inside li, good, bad or neutral for SEO?

Tags: html, forms, seo, html-lists

Recently, after some discussions, I decided to use List for social buttons such as Google+, Facebook-like and twitter-follow. Example (under Follow us Section):
[image]

I would like to know if using Form inside List item (`<li>`) has any effect in SEO. If it has, what's the effect?

Simply - is it right to use form inside `<li>` as shown in the example above?


Thank you very much!

Comment: Are you really concerned about the SEO for *social media buttons*?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There’s no reason to think that nesting a form inside a list item would affect search engine behavior. What search engines do with forms in the first place is a different matter, and depends on the form and on the search engine.